# ¿Cómo elaborar gráfico de barras apiladas en R utilizando ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo esta tabla compuesta por la columna "vendedor" y en las otras columnas las fechas de reporte de cuánto vendió cada vendedor:

```
> tabla
  vendedor 2021-11-30 2021-12-31
1   Carlos      16660      11560
2     Juna      16560      13560
```

¿Cómo puedo mostrar esto en R utilizando `ggplot2`, para que se vea de la siguiente manera?:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
tabla <- read.table(text = "vendedor  2021-11-30 2021-12-31
    Carlos  16660    11560
    Juna    16560    13560", sep = "",
    header = TRUE,
    check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Bienvenido fordgtpanama a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero es hacer el `data.frame` mas "amigable" con `ggplot`:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
vendedor,2021-11-30,2021-12-31
Carlos,16660,11560
Juna,16560,13560", sep=',', header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-vendedor, names_to='fecha') -> df

df

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  vendedor fecha      value
  <chr>    <chr>      <int>
1 Carlos   2021-11-30 16660
2 Carlos   2021-12-31 11560
3 Juna     2021-11-30 16560
4 Juna     2021-12-31 13560
```

Con  `pivot_longer()` transformamos los datos originales en un formato "largo", y ahora es más simple elaborar el gráfico:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x=fecha, y=value, fill=vendedor)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]